# Faulty calculation of position of "Rows per page" menu in a v-data-table

Tags: wordpress, vuetify.js

### Faulty positioning of "rows per page" in a vue-data-table

When using the component **[v-data-table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#api)** the calculation of the menu **Rows per page** in the subcomponent subcomponent **v-data-footer** is faulty. Please see screenshot below.

After some research I found out, that the **[menu components](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/)** have their positioning context attached to the **root v-app component** by default and that there is a prop called `attach` to configure that behavior.

Weirdly the real position of the app is ignored and it seems to be assumed that the app has it's top left corner at 0px/0px. I experimented and gave my app a fixed positioning in the top left corner - positioning of the menu works correctly then. Otherwise it is off on x-Axis (relative position due to surrounding grid system) and also y-Axis (height of admin bar and header).

My vue app runs in a WordPress context. A bunch of mini-apps to render data from other plugins via shortcodes. This worked fine so far (minor styling issues), except for the positioning of those menus when using Vuetify.

I guess a solution might be to set the attach prop for the pagination menu, but research and documentation did not help so far on how to do that in a v-data-table. I would be grateful for any hint.

I tried to recreate a similar [situation in a CodePen](https://codepen.io/Sixl/pen/oNxBaeQ), the y-offset behaves slightly different though.

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot of App in WordPress context with the menu positioning being way off]

Comment: After doing some more research, it seems like positioning problems with the menu elements are quite common in Vuetify, when people try to use the app in another context or want to use parent elements with different positioning, created by plugins etc.
For now I think the only solution is to move to a library that has components which can be used more independently. I guess Vuetify just follows another approach.

Answer (score 0):

After checking your code in codepen, I fixed some parts.
Please check this codepen.
https://codepen.io/plsdev89/pen/qBZRQKd

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">

    <div id="wpadminbar">WP Admin Bar</div>

    <header id="header">Header</header>

    <div id="wrapper">
      <main>
        <h2>Vue App</h2>
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="desserts"
          :items-per-page="4"
          class="elevation-1"
        ></v-data-table>

      </main>
      <aside>
        <h3>Sidebar<h3>  
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem</li>
          <li>Lorem</li>
          <li>Lorem</li>
          <li>Lorem</li>
          <li>Lorem</li>
        </ul>
      </aside>  
    <div>    
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But the pen  was just an example for clarification of the effect. I cannot surround WordPress with a  <v-app> tag. The app is inside of the grid system of a WordPress page. In your example you have the app at coordinate 0/0. This is not my problem. Guess I will have to provide a full example in a WP environment online, so that it is less misleading. Sorry for not being more clear in my question.

Comment: I have several <v-app> rendered inside a wordpress theme. This means that each <v-app> has parents with relative positioning and a lot of other elemnts above and below. Due to the nature of the vue-data-table it calculates from top left corner by default. Which works fine if the app is in the top left corner, like in the example you provided. This is not the case in my situation. I hope this makes it clearer. I work on a more suitable code example.

Comment: Did you find a solution?